# Updating a field from a different DAC

Tags: customization, acumatica

I created a customization on the service order as shown below. When Mark for SO is active, CREATE SALES ORDER button appears. The button enable creation of a service management sales order.

[image: image of the screen]

The service management sales order is as follows;

[image: image of the created sales order]

How do I get the  STATUS and ORDERNBR of  service management sales order created to be displayed on Servce order screen on the Details Line on my custom fields i.e SOStatus(UsrSOStatus). also have another custom field as SONumber(UsrSONumber).

Comment: Hi @DevFuture. I would add more code detail on what you tried or have in place. In general you just need to update cache with your value.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure there is a SOOrder foreign key written to FSSODet in a cache extension that is filled out when a sales order is created
2. In a row selecting event for FSSODet, select the SOOrder record using SOOrder.PK.Find(), and put the status value of the record in your unbound field UsrSOStatus
3. Make sure that your UsrSOStatus field has the same drop down list attribute that SOOrder.status uses.